# spring-xd stream closed - python module

Tags: spring-xd

whenever I'm trying to use python module in spring-xd, I'm getting below error:

```
[ stream create pytest --definition "time | shell --command='python /home/Ubuntu/xd/echo2.py' --encoder=LF | log" --deploy]
[]

2016-03-21T19:23:38+0000 1.2.0.RELEASE INFO DeploymentsPathChildrenCache-0 container.DeploymentListener - Path cache event: path=/deployments/modules/allocated/ed02510e-f8b3-4f53-9848-e2268fbbade1/pytest.processor.shell.1, type=CHILD_ADDED
2016-03-21T19:23:38+0000 1.2.0.RELEASE INFO DeploymentsPathChildrenCache-0 container.DeploymentListener - Deploying module 'shell' for stream 'pytest'
2016-03-21T19:23:38+0000 1.2.0.RELEASE INFO DeploymentsPathChildrenCache-0 container.DeploymentListener - Deploying module [ModuleDescriptor@1c30c1dd moduleName = 'shell', moduleLabel = 'shell', group = 'pytest', sourceChannelName = [null], sinkChannelName = [null], index = 1, type = processor, parameters = map['command' -> 'python /home/Ubuntu/xd/echo2.py', 'encoder' -> 'LF'], children = list[[empty]]]
2016-03-21T19:23:39+0000 1.2.0.RELEASE ERROR SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1 process.ShellCommandProcessor - python: can't open file '/home/Ubuntu/xd/echo2.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
2016-03-21T19:23:39+0000 1.2.0.RELEASE INFO DeploymentsPathChildrenCache-0 container.DeploymentListener - Path cache event: path=/deployments/modules/allocated/ed02510e-f8b3-4f53-9848-e2268fbbade1/pytest.source.time.1, type=CHILD_ADDED
2016-03-21T19:23:39+0000 1.2.0.RELEASE INFO DeploymentsPathChildrenCache-0 container.DeploymentListener - Deploying module 'time' for stream 'pytest'
2016-03-21T19:23:39+0000 1.2.0.RELEASE INFO DeploymentsPathChildrenCache-0 container.DeploymentListener - Deploying module [ModuleDescriptor@5133da1 moduleName = 'time', moduleLabel = 'time', group = 'pytest', sourceChannelName = [null], sinkChannelName = [null], index = 0, type = source, parameters = map[[empty]], children = list[[empty]]]
2016-03-21T19:23:39+0000 1.2.0.RELEASE INFO DeploymentSupervisor-0 zk.ZKStreamDeploymentHandler - Deployment status for stream 'pytest': DeploymentStatus{state=deployed}
2016-03-21T19:23:39+0000 1.2.0.RELEASE ERROR task-scheduler-1 process.ShellCommandProcessor - Stream closed
java.io.IOException: Stream closed
        at java.lang.ProcessBuilder$NullOutputStream.write(ProcessBuilder.java:434) ~[na:1.7.0_95]
        at java.io.OutputStream.write(OutputStream.java:116) ~[na:1.7.0_95]
        at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flushBuffer(BufferedOutputStream.java:82) ~[na:1.7.0_95]
        at java.io.BufferedOutputStream.flush(BufferedOutputStream.java:140) ~[na:1.7.0_95]
        at org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.serializer.ByteArraySingleTerminatorSerializer.serialize(ByteArraySingleTerminatorSerializer.java:94) ~[spring-integration-ip-4.1.5.RELEASE.jar!/:na]
```

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, 9 times out of 10, that has been caused by the python process crashing behind the scenes and the XD processor being unaware of it.  Check your logs for the python process to verify that it's still running.